# Magento: Setting the first order number issued

Tags: orders

When completing the first order placement at a Magento store
the order number issued by default is 100000001. I would like
to set is to something smaller (since there aren't that many
items in the store) and would also like the number to be
more random-looking (for instance 576). The reason is
that I don't want customers knowing they are the first
customer and would rather they thought there had been
other orders before theirs. I think it would make
the store more discreet.

Is there a way to set the first order number
value returned in the following message,
prior to a store's launch? Here is
what my test instance of the
frontend displayed upon
placing the very first
order:

---

Your order has been received.
Thank you for your purchase!

Your order # is: 100000001.

You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **shorten the number** you can edit the `increment_pad_length` column in the `eav_entity_type` table.

If you want to **change the order increment id** you can edit the `increment_last_id` column in the `eav_entity_store` table. If there isn't an entry yet (e.g. when you never ordered in the store) you don't have to do anything. If there is an entry, in theory you also can just delete the row for the store as it will be recreated.

You can change the values by creating an **upgrade script** and putting it in to the `data` folder.

An example `app/code/local/Emzee/Example/data/emzee_example_setup/data-install-0.0.1.php` script:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')
    ->loadByCode('order')
    ->setIncrementPadLength(6)
    ->save();

$storeCode = "store_code";
$store = Mage::getModel("core/store")->load($storeCode);

$entityStore = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')->loadByEntityStore($entityType->getEntityTypeId(), $store->getId());
if (!$entityStore->getId()) {
    $entityStore
        ->setEntityTypeId($entityType->getEntityTypeId())
        ->setStoreId($store->getId())
        ->setIncrementPrefix(1)
        ->setIncrementLastId(1000576)
        ->save();
}    

$installer->endSetup();
```

You can do the same for **invoices, creditmemos and shipments** if you like.

If you already have orders in your (non-production) system you may want to delete all entries in the database to avoid collisions and/our confusion.

These queries can be used to **delete** quote, order, invoice, shipment and creditmemo data in an Magento EE installation. For CE there may not be all of the tables available.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set or reset your increment id in this table

```
eav_entity_store
```

You can set the increment prefix and the last increment id